# How to properly link to a C library in cython C++ build

Tags: python, cython, setuptools, htslib

I have a compiled C library `htslib` in my module top-level directory, this is first built using `./configure; make` outside of python before running `python setup.py install`. I am trying to use headers listed in `htslib`. I have cython scripts e.g. `script.pyx` which wrap supporting header files `cpp_header.h`, but these are compiled using C++ via the setup script. Setup of the python module runs without problems, but at runtime `htslib` symbols are missing, I get `ImportError: foo.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: hts_close`. My directory structure is:

```
foo/
    htslib/  # c library
        objectfiles.o
        htslib/
           headers.h 
        cram/
           more_headers.h
           more_objects.o
    foo/
       script.pyx
       cpp_header.h    # c++ 
    setup.py
```

In my setup script I list some libraries needed for `htslib`, some `library_dirs`, `include_dirs`, and `extra_compile_args` for building the `Extension`:

```
root = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
htslib = os.path.join(root, "htslib") 

libraries = [htslib]  

library_dirs = [htslib, numpy.get_include(), root, "htslib", "foo"]
include_dirs = [numpy.get_include(), root, htslib]
for item in ["htslib", "cram"]:
    include_dirs.append(os.path.join(htslib, item))

ext_modules.append(Extension(f"foo.script",
                             [f"foo/script.pyx"],
                             libraries=libraries,
                             library_dirs=library_dirs,
                             include_dirs=include_dirs,
                             extra_compile_args=extras,
                             define_macros=[("NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API", "NPY_1_7_API_VERSION")],
                             language="c++"))
```

Additionally, I also add `htslib` to the `package_data` option in `setup`:

```
setup(...
      packages=["foo"],
      package_data={"foo": ["htslib/*"]},
      ext_modules=cythonize(ext_modules),
      ...
)
```

Inside the `cpp_header.h` file the htslib headers are included as:

```
#include "../htslib/htslib/sam.h"
```

Im trying this on unix. Would any one know how I can get this working?

Comment: Do I miss it, or is `htslib` not in your `libraries`? If not, how is it supposed to be used by the linker?

Comment: hmm. I just tried adding the absolute path to the hstlib folder, into the libraries, but still got the same error